# Which column for foreign key: id or any other column and why?

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys

## TL;DR

1. Should a foreign key always refer to the id column of another table? Why or why not? Is there a standard rule for this?
2. Is there a cost associated with using any other unique column other than `id` column for foreign key? Performance / storage? How significant? Is it frowned in the industry?

Example: this is the schema for my sample problem:

[image]

In my schema sometimes I use `id` column as the foreign key and sometimes use some other data column.

- In `vehicle_detail` table I use a `unique` `size` column as a foreign key from `vehicle_size` table and `unique` `color` column as the foreign key from `vehicle_color` table.
- But in `vehicle_user` I used the `user_identifier_id` as a foreign key which refers to `id` primary key column in `user_identifier` table.

Which is the correct way?

On a side note, I don't have `id` columns for the `garage_level`, `garage_spaceid`, `vehicle_garage_status` and `vehicle_parking_status` tables because they only have one column which is the primary key and the data they store is just at most 15 rows in each table and it is probably never going to change. Should I still have an `id` column in those ?

Comment: The rule is a FK needs to refer to a `UNIQUE` column or set of columns. A `Primary Key` by definition is unique. If your `id` is a PK then it qualifies but it is not a rule that it be the referenced column(s).  As to the small tables all you need is a PK on whatever column or columns that qualify.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Okay so as long as it is a Unique column even 1 column table is fine. But what about the situation where I have two unique keys (ex. `id` and `phone_no` in `user_identifier` table) and I can't decide which key to be the foreign key for another table ? Is there a rule for that ? Mabybe because `id` numbers are small they are preferred ? Or I just go by preference ?

Comment: I would say stick with whatever you think will change the least. Phone numbers change and they get reassigned to new people.

Comment: Your question should be corrected a bit: "Which column(**s**)".  Note that a) FK must target PK or unique constraint, b) it's better if column(s) in FK are changed the least. Otherwise it's absolutely OK to have multiple columns in FK - you don't need to always create a surrogate key especially for FK

Comment: What is your 1 (clear specific researched non-duplicate) question? [ask] [Help] Where are you 1st stuck in what presentation of what information modelling & DB design reference/textbook? If youi aren't following one, what do you expect us to say, since (re)writing one to explain to you means your question is too broad?

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: @philipxy Can you give a link to instruction how to write ERDs in a text form? Does SO supports `mermaid` now or something similar? I did not found any

Comment: @AlexYu It's just names of tables & attributes plus participations/FKs (referencing & referenced table/entity/association & attribute list). The formal DB equivalent is "DDL" but informal would be considered a pseudo-DDL, a kind of pseudo-code. Most tools to compose ERDs have a way to dump a DDL/text version, maybe called generating DB definition code. But if an asker won't type it in (and please, only what is relevant to a specific question about being 1st stuck) why would they expect answerers to? Anyway this will be in any information modeling & DB design text, & google, & it's a SO faq.

Comment: These are faqs. Please before considering posting read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask], [Help] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Please ask just 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question per post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A foreign key has to target a primary key or unique constraint. It is normal to reference the primary key, because you typically want to reference an individual row in another table, and the primary key is the identifier of a table row.

From a technical point of view, it does not matter whether a foreign key references the primary key or another unique constraint, because in PostgreSQL both are implemented in the same way, using a unique index.

As to your concrete examples, there is nothing wrong with having the unique `size` column of `vehicle_size` be the target of a foreign key, although it begs the question why you didn't make `size` the primary key and omit the `id` column altogether. There is no need for each table to have an `id` column that is the automatically generated numeric primary key, except that there may be ORMs and other software that expect that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @LaurenzAlbe . I just updated the question to be more clear.

Comment: @Yahyaa Ideally you'd want something that uniquely and forever identifies the target row. Your `phone_no` may be unique but can it change? If someone can change their phone number (which happens all the time really) then it probably isn't a good choice for use with FKs.

Comment: I think it should be noted that PK or unique constraint don't need to be a defined on single column. I saw a lot of cases when a surrogate key was created only to support FK. Especially when a surrogate was created with `uuid` (16 bytes) when an existing unique was `int`+`date` (4 bytes + 4 bytes = 8 bytes)

Comment: Thanks for another quick and clear response @LaurenzAlbe . That almost answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

A foreign key is a field or a column that is used to establish a link between two tables. A FOREIGN KEY is a column (or collection of columns) in one table, that refers to the PRIMARY KEY in another table.

There is no rule that it should refer to a `id` column but the column it refers to should be the primary key. In real scenarios, it usually refers to `Id` column  as in most cases it is the primary key in the tables.

Answer (score 1):

A **foreign** key is basically a column of a different table(it is always of a different table, since that is the role it serves). It is used to join/ get data from a different table. Think of it like say school is a database and there are many different table for different aspects of student.
say by using Admission number 1234, from accounts table you can get the fees and sports table you can get the sports he play.
Now there is no rule that foreign key should be id column, you can keep it whatever you want. But,to use foreign key you should have a matching column in both tables therefore usually id column is only used. As I stated in the above example the only common thing in say sports table and accounts table would be admission number.

```
 admn_no | sports     |
+---------+------------+
|    1234 | basketball


+---------+---------+
| admn_no | fees    |
+---------+---------+
|    1234 | 1000000 |
+---------+---------+
```

Now say using the query\

```
select * from accounts join sports using (admn_no);
```

you will get:

```
+---------+---------+------------+
| admn_no | fees    | sports     |
+---------+---------+------------+
|    1234 | 1000000 | basketball |
+---------+---------+------------+
```

PS: sorry for bad formatting

Answer (score 1):

OP question is about "correct way".

I will try to provide some kind of summary from existing comments and answers, general `DO` and general `DONT` for FKs.

### What was already said

#### A. "A foreign key has to target a primary key or unique constraint"

Literally from  [Laurenz Albe answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69202937/1168212) and it was noted in comments

#### B. "stick with whatever you think will change the least"

It was noted by [Adrian Klavier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7070613/adrian-klaver) in comments.

#### Notes

There is no such general rule that PK or unique constraint must be defined on a single column.

So the question title itself must be corrected: "Which column(**s**) for foreign key: id or any other column(**s**) and why?"

Let's talk about "why".

### Why: General DO, general DONT and an advice

> Is there a cost associated with using any other unique column other than id column for foreign key? Performance / storage? How significant? Is it frowned in the industry?

**General DO**: Analyze requirements, use logic, use math (arithmetics is enough usually). There is no a single database design that's always good for all cases. Always ask yourself: "Can it be improved?". Never be content with design of existing FKs, if requirements changed or DBMS changed or storage options changed - revise design.

**General DONT**: Don't think that there is a single correct rule for all cases. Don't think: "if that worked in that database/table than it will work for this case too".

Let me illustrate this points with a common example.

### Example: PK on `id uuid` field

1. We look into database and see a table has a unique constraint on two fields of types `integer` (4 bytes) + `date` (4 bytes)
2. Additionally: this table has a field `id` of `uuid` type (16 bytes)
3. PK is defined on `id`
4. All FKs from other tables are targeting `id` field

It this a correct design or not?

##### Case A. Common case - not OK

Let's use math:

- unique constraint on `int`+`date`: it's 4+4=8 bytes
- data is never changed
- so it's a good candidate for primary key in this table
- and nothing prevents to use it for foreign keys in related tables

So it looks like additional 16 bytes per each row + indexes costs is a mistake.

*And that's a very common mistake especially in combination of MSSQL + CLUSTERED indexes on random uuids*

Is it always a mistake?

No.

Consider latter cases.

#### Case B. Distributed system - OK

Suppose that you have a distributed system:

- `ServerA`, `ServerB`, `ServerC` are sources of data
- `HeadServer` - is data aggregator
- data on `serverA`-`ServerC` could be duplicated: the same record could exists on several instances
- aggregated data must not have duplicates
- data for related tables can come from different instances: data for table with PK from `serverA` and data for tables with FKs from `serverB`-`serverC`
- you need to log from where each record is originated

In such case existence of PK on `id uuid` is justified:

- unique constraint allows to deduplicate records
- surrogate key allows related data come from different sources

#### Case C. 'id' is used to expose data through API - OK

Suppose that you have an API to access data for external consumers.

There is a good unique constraint on:

- `client_id`: incrementing integer in range 1..100000
- `invoice_date`: dates '20100101'..'20210901'

And a surrogate key on `id` with random uuids.

You can create external API in forms:

- `/server/invoice/{client_id}/{invoice_date}`
- `/server/invoice/{id}`

From security POV `/{id}` is superior by reasons:

- it's impossible to deduce from one `uuid` value existence of other
- it's easier to implement authorization system for entities of different types. E.g. entityA has natural key on `int`, entityB on `bigint' and entityC on`  int`+` byte`+`date`

In such case surrogate key not only justified but becames essential.

### Afterword

I hope that I was clear in explanation of main correct principle: "There is no such thing as a universal correct principle".

An additional advice: **avoid CASCADE UPDATE/DELETEs**:
Although it depends on DBMS you use.

But in general :

- "explicit is better than implicit"
- CASCADEs rarely works as intended
- when CASCADES works - usually they have performance problems

Thank you for your attention.

I hope this helps somebody.

Comment: This definitely helps me. Thanks for taking out your time to answer my question in such detail. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Yahyaa take a look at this question too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69226319/why-composite-primary-key-when-i-can-use-single-primary-key-with-unique-constrai Essentially it discusses the same topic