# Why Composite Primary key when I can use Single Primary key with Unique constraints on composite columns?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-schema

I am in a situation where I am thinking of changing my tables schemas from a single primary key to a composite primary key.

This change will affect many of my tables and the SQL statements (Especially join queries) written to query such tables.

Having done some research on the benefits of the composite key approach, I found one major selling point is it's use to enforce uniqueness of the composite columns.

However, I can still leave my single primary key tables and then add a unique constraints to enforce uniqueness on the composite columns like this:

```
create table ... (
 id primary key not null,
 column1 ...
 column2 ...
 .
 .
 columnN ...
 unique(column1, column2) // added this line to my existing tables
)
```

Now to the questions:

What are the benefits of either approaches?

Explicitly defining a composite primary key or using a single primary key with unique constraints on the composite columns. Why?

Comment: Does the `id`  field have meaning? In other words is it just some variation of auto-increment that provides unique integers or does it have some higher level meaning? Why are you feeling the need to make a change? Is there something that a single PK is not providing?

Comment: Try to make your PK as simple as possible - so if a single column is sufficient - always favor this over a compound PK. It makes joining from other tables just that much easier!

Comment: First, think about how should it be. Which columns uniquely identify your rows? The ID or the ID+column1+column2? Also, PK(id)+UC(c1, c2) is different from PK(id, c1, c2). For a more theoretical view, check this. The examples part is very interesting in my opinion: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: @Adrian, the `id` is used as a foreign key for other tables and it simplifies my join queries. No need for using `AND` in my join statements

Comment: Please add responses as updates to your question so others don't have to search through the comments. Also did you see the rest of my questions in my comment? They where an after thought that you may not  have seen on first read.

Comment: I think, if you want to be unique 2 columns create a unique index (constraint). This is the best solution. If you make composite PK, you have to change joins in the whole db, and rewrite / recreate FK columns! And duplicate  columns.

Comment: @marc_s exactly my thoughts. I feel the composite key is going to make me write more codes without bringing in significant benefits.

Comment: Take a look on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69213338/1168212 . It discusses merits of PKs on a singe field vs composite keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a primary key to enforce uniqueness.  You can use a `unique` constraint or index instead.

I am not a fan of composite primary keys.  Here are some reasons:

- All foreign key references have to include all the keys in the correct order and matching types.  This makes is slightly more cumbersome to define those tables.
- Because the composite keys are included in all referencing tables, those tables are often *larger*, which results in worse performance.
- If you decide that you want to change the type of one of the component keys -- say the length of a string or an `int` to a `numeric` -- you have to modify lots and lots of tables.
- When joining tables, you have to include all the keys.  If you miss one . . . well, the code is syntactically correct but the results are wrong.

There are occasions where composite keys are acceptable, such as tables that have no foreign key references.  Even in those cases, I use synthetic keys, but I totally understand the other perspective.

Comment: "The other perspective": there is a cost for supporting surrogate key and indexes for them. E.g. I think it's hard to justify in a general case a surrogate with `uuid` (16 bytes) when natural key is `int`+`date` (4+4 bytes) - and I saw a lot of such examples.

Comment: @AlexYu . . . Interesting.  I wouldn't recommend a UUID for a primary key unless a business purpose requires it.  Integers are much more efficient.

Comment: UUIDs makes sense in distributed systems. But I saw them a lot in cases when `bigint` or even `int` would be enough. Maybe as result of ORM code generators - anyway it's always pain and misery

Comment: "The other perspective" extended: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69232737/1168212

Answer (score 2):

I will speak from "other perspective" [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69226701/1168212) by Gordon Linoff.

In general I'm "pro" composite keys.

I consider synthetic keys as an optimization technique which is commonly overused and sometimes it becames a pessimization without any merits, just because programmers accustomed to it.

### Example of overusing synthetic keys

- there is a table with a unique constraint on `int`(4 bytes) and `date`(4 bytes) fields
- they are never changed
- but anyway somebody adds a `uuid` (16 bytes) field with random values
- and define a PK on it

Let's analyze it:

- **Arithmetics**: adding 16 bytes on each row + index costs is not an optimization it's a pessimization
- **Code**: I don't think that adding one `AND` really hurts
- **Semantics**: natural key holds some business value, synthetic key - not

Don't think that it's an imaginary counter example just for the sake of argument -  I saw a lot of such synthetic keys.

#### Notes:

A. **`uuid` keys could be justified** in some cases, I described them in https://stackoverflow.com/a/69213338/1168212

B. Even bigint (8 bytes) surrogate key is not much better: it's 8 bytes per row + index cost for nothing.

C. Dangerous scenario: all application code is written around synthetic key, then in one day somebody stumbles on unique constraint violation and a "bright" idea came to him how to "fix" it: remove unique constraint! Rejoice! App starts working! Realization of harsh truth comes later.

Don't laugh: I saw the latter multiple times.

### Viable cases for synthetic keys

A. **A lot of fields in unique constraint**. I consider: 2 fields are OK, 3 - so-so, 4-5-more - it becames cumbersome to write all `AND`s and prone to errors in code, so I would consider synthetic key

B. **Length of fields in unique constraint is big**. E.g. you have combination of `varchar` and `uuid` in unique constraint and synthetic integer key serves like optimization technique

C. **Data in unique constraint updated frequently**. Then synthetic key

D. **Rule for unique constraint can change during lifetime of system**. You know that entities are related but you expect that rule can change with new business requirements. Then synthetic key will solve this.

E. **Data warehouse designed in [Dimensional Modelling](https://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/)**. Design of such databases starts from design of surrogate keys

F. **Other requirements like a need for fine-grained authorization** for all entities in database.

### Summary

I think that there is no such universal rule exists suitable for all cases.

Synthetic keys has their cost:

- don't stick with a single rule
- analyze requirements
- do math
- consider from coding perspective